# Capture output of tests in gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy

How do I capture the standard output and standard error from all test tasks in gradle?   For exec tasks, I can just say standardOutput = new ByteAr... and it works - but test tasks don't seem to have a standard out.

What I'm looking to achieve is simple. (Actually, I want this for ALL gradle tasks, but test tasks are most important).

If the task succeeds... 
    I get no output at all
If the task fails
    I get the most detailed output possible.

Simple as that.  How do I achieve this?

Comment: Not sure you really need that. The build/test-results directory contains all the information about the run unit tests, including the stdout and stderr output.

Comment: all our builds run in a build farm.  Compare the time spent looking at text in the build log sent - with logging into the build server, going to the workspace, figuring out where the test output is, figuring out which test failed, finding the test, and finding the output.   Having the details of the failing test there in the output is a significant savings.  If we only save each dev 15 mins a day, and this would do that _easily_ - over our team of 20 that's 1000 man hours a year...

Comment: Depends on your build server, Jenkins for example provides via a plugin test statistics and allows direct access to test results (including test output) via the UI. No need to dig into the workspace.

Comment: wanted to bump this. also looking for a solution. the ability to get the logs in real time via an output stream (sent into a file or something) is what i was looking for. @Henry do you know if those test-results files (the html, the xml, or the binary bin files) are generated in real time? or only appear when gradle is done running?

Comment: looks like those files do not get generated in real time. but after a bunch of searching, i think i found the feature to use: `test.onOutput`. see the example [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:onOutput(groovy.lang.Closure)). using this you can hook into the `stdout`/`stderr` events from tests and use it to write to a file using something like an `OutputStreamWriter`